# jetty-maven-plugin NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: maven, tomcat, log4j, jetty, war

I created maven parent module with two maven children. It is web based application in war output that is deployed to Tomcat directory.The problem is that for testing war file I have to start Tomcat and test the app. For this scenario I decided to use jetty maven plugin in parent POM.xml file. Here is how it looks like:

```
<modules>
    <module>hellojavaworld</module>
    <module>application</module>
</modules>




  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.5</source>
      <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>


  <plugin>
       <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
       <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
      <configuration>
            <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
             <webApp>
              <contextPath>/hellojavaworld</contextPath>           
             </webApp>   
         <war>c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.64\webapps\hellojavaworld.war</war>
        </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

If I start Tomcat manually and use http://localhost:8080/hellojavaworld it works fine.
On the other hand when used

> mvn jetty:run-war

it works,but got stucks on error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /hellojavaworld/HelloServlet. Reason: 

Server Error

Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
```

I know this problem is very common,because of the missing jars. I know that these jars are placed in c:\apache-tomcat-7.0.64\lib\ folder.

So the question is how to tell the jetty to use this folder as external jars for my war file?

> Note: for the Tomcat itself it runs,there is just problem with jetty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty doesn't use log4j.

Why would you expect the Web Container to provide your WebApp logging outside of the servlet spec?

> See the various [`ServletContext.log()` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#log-java.lang.String-) for actual servlet spec logging

Suggestion: Put your log4j jar files in your webapp's `WEB-INF/lib/`

Comment: Is there any workaround to use another plugin instead of jetty? I do not want to change my pom.xml creating jars in lib folder  for now.

Comment: If you bounce around to other web containers you'll find that few use or provide log4j.  Even on those containers you'll still need to include log4j in your `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks a lot. I have changed the configuration of maven war plugin to the way it includes all the necessary jars and puts them to WEB-INF/lib folder and it works like Mercedes!